# JQuery delay keyup search

Tags: jquery

I have this code to hide every `.flip` element except the one I searched for:

```
var $rows = $('.flip'); 
$('#search').keyup(function() 
{
    var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();  
    $rows.show().filter(function()                                      
    {
        var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        return !~text.indexOf(val);
    }).hide();  
});
```

The problem with this is that it searches every time I release a key. How can I make it to wait until I stopped typing

Thanks!

Comment: Use `change` event instead of `keyup`.

Comment: @Azim `change` is a risky one, some browsers/platforms will only fire it after the element loses focus, which isn't usually what you'd want in a search feature.

Comment: `keyup` and `change` won't pick up pasting the text via mouse for example, so he should use `input` event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `setTimeout`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var timer;

  var $rows = $('.flip');
  var $self = $(this);

  $('#search').keyup(function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);

    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      $('#test').text(Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000));
      var val = $.trim($self.val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

      $rows.show().filter(function() {
        var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        return !~text.indexOf(val);
      }).hide();
    }, 300);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search"/>
<span id="test"></span>
```

Comment: @Hiroo17 My Example does not work for you? Console errors?

Comment: Your example works fine, but the moment I implement it in my code it doesn"t work.

Comment: I must have fckd up somewhere. Anyway. Your code should work so I mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use debounce, I suggest [lodash](https://lodash.com) for it.

I use it like this:

```
var debounce = _.debounce(search, 500, false);

$('#search-input').on('change', function() {
  debounce(this);
});

function search(input) {
  if(input.value.length > 2) {
    ...
  }
}
```

[_.debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#debounce) will do the job of waiting for the user stop inserting value.

The first parameter is the function you want to call after it waits the user stop inserting value.

The second parameter is the time in milliseconds it'll wait for a next value inserting.

The third parameter is an option for configuration, using false will make it send the last value inserted.